# Gradle react-native Error

Tags: android, react-native

I get this Error when i run  `react-native run-android` :

```
Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat installDebug)...
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

I googled checked some solutions on stack overflow
i tried

```
gradle wrapper
```

It never worked.  I am using `gradle 2.8`  and `react-native: "0.47.1"`

What could be the right fix